# How to join my mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

Normally I do this way to get 2 tables

```
<?php 
$select = "SELECT * FROM question ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,20";
$query  = $db->query($select);

while ($fetch = $db->fetch($query)) {
    $uselect = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id='".intval($fetch['q_user'])."' ";
    $uquery  = $db->query($uselect);
    $ufetch = $db->fetch($uquery);
    ?>    

    Title : <?php echo $fetch['q_title']; ?>
    User : <?php echo $ufetch['u_id']; ?>

    <?php 
} 
?>
```

There have a simple way to join this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could do:

```
SELECT *
FROM question
JOIN user ON question.q_user = user.id
ORDER BY question.id DESC
LIMIT 0, 20
```

One thing I'd suggest, is explicitly listing the columns, since any overlap (Question.id and user.id) will be ambiguous.  Simply do `SELECT question.id, user.id AS uid, ...`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM question JOIN user ON question.q_user = user.id ORDER BY question.id DESC LIMIT 0, 20
```

Useful link: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from question left join user on user.id = question.q_user order by question.id desc limit 0,20;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM question 
LEFT JOIN user ON user.id = question.q_user
ORDER BY question.id DESC LIMIT 0,20
```

Answer (score 0):

This query should be right:

```
create table questions
 (
    question_id bigint unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    user_id bigint unsigned not null,
    title varchar(255),
 )engine=innodb;

 create table users
 (
    user_id bigint unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(255) not null
 )engine=innodb;

 // your query
 select q.* from questions q
 inner join users u where u.user_id = q.user_id
 order by q.question_id desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i am assuming you are wanting to return the user that asked a question, because you store the q_user then you need to do some SQL like:

"SELECT q.q_title, u.u_id FROM question q JOIN user u ON (q.q_user=u.u_id)"

You can apply your limits etc to this query.